# Windows Form Application Touch Gesture

Tags: c#, windows-8, touch, .net-4.5

We are developing a C#, .NET 4.5 application.  On Windows 8.1, whenever a user does touch scrolling on one of the panels in the form, the entire screen application moves just a bit, even if maximized.

Found questions asked where people having similar issues fixed it in WPF by turning off the boundary feedback event, and people who fixed it in Windows 7 by just turning off boundary feedback for all of Windows.  However, I can't find anything for disabling this in a standard C# windows form application, and the boundary feedback setting option doesn't seem to exist in the Windows 8 settings.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I believe you can override the [WM_GESTURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353242(v=vs.85).aspx) message (specifically GID_PAN) and not send it on.

The default code is likely very similar to the example code in [UpdatePanningFeedback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317336(v=vs.85).aspx) .